# How to enable/disable fancy comparison signs in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: editor, jetbrains-ide, appearance, ligature

My PyCharm changes the appearance of comparison symbols as I type them.
For example, if I type "`>=`", it turns it into the way you'd write it in a math notebook, like so:

[image: example of rendered comparison operator]

I couldn't find where in PyCharm's setting that is so I could disable it, or enable it in friends' installations where it doesn't work that way (the sign just remains `>=`).

Where's the setting to disable this special rendering of comparison operators?

I tried googling for the answer in several different phrasings and didn't find anything useful.

This question should also apply to other JetBrains IDEs such as IntelliJ IDEA and CLion.

Comment: Welcome! Can you [edit] to share _what_ you googled for? That way, people in the future who are trying to google for those phrasings have a chance at finding this Q&A post.

Answer (score 1):

This called a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)). Go look at what font your IDE is using. It's probably [JetBrains Mono](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/), which supports many ligatures for programming operators and such.

To disable it, go to the font settings, and uncheck the box that says "Enable font ligatures".

Or alternatively, you can switch to a font that doesn't have ligatures in it.